# How to configure Azure Databricks cluster to use Java 11

Tags: java, databricks, azure-databricks

I would like to configure Azure Databricks cluster to use Java 11 instead of 8

I added the following property under **Advanced Options > Spark > Environment Variables**:

```
JNAME=zulu11-ca-amd64
```

and restarted the cluster. Unfortunately, I still see that Spark Conf (Cluster --> Spark Cluster UI -> Runtime information) is configured to use java 8

##### Runtime Information

```
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca-amd64/jre
```

```
Java Version: 1.8.0_362 (Azul Systems, Inc.)
```

Comment: what Databricks Runtime are you using?

Comment: @AlexOtt I tested it against  13.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.4.0, Scala 2.12). It doesn't have to be this version. I selected the latest one available. If it is possible to change version of Java in other runtimes then it would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested on the DBR 11.3, 13.0 & 12.2 and everything works just fine. As [per doc](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/10.0.html#cluster-support-for-jdk-11-public-preview) - add following environment variable:

```
JNAME=zulu11-ca-amd64
```

[image]

and you get a cluster with Java 11:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @AlexOtt for checking it. I am pretty sure I did the same. Anyway, let me double check it. I will keep you posted. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: It did not work for me.  I added same in env variables.  But still my java version says 1.8 in cluster.